# passing arguments to a node script coming from stdin

Tags: node.js, shell

### overview

I'd like to pass arguments to a node script coming from stdin.

generally, I'm shooting for something like this

```
nodeScript.js | node {{--attach-args??}} --verbose --dry-run
```

that would act the same as

```
node nodeScript.js --verbose --dry-run
```

#### more detail

here's a boiled down script *for illustration*, `dumpargs.js`

```
console.log("the arguments you passed in were");
console.log(process.argv);
console.log("");
```

so you could then:

```
node dumpargs.js --verbose --dry-run file.txt
[ 'node',
  '/home/bill-murray/Documents/dumpargs.js',
  '--verbose',
  '--dry-run',
  'file.js' ]
```

now the question, if that script comes in across stdin (say, via `cat` or `curl`)

```
cat dumpars.js | node
the arguments you passed in were
[ 'node' ]
```

is there a good way to pass arguments to it?

> **not node**: with bash, using `dumpargs.sh` this time
>
> ```
> echo "the arguments you passed in were"
> printf "> $@"
> echo
> ```
>
> the answer would look like
>
> ```
> cat dumpargs.sh | bash -s - "--verbose --dry-run file.txt"
> the arguments you passed in were
> >  --verbose --dry-run file.txt
> ```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a specific syntax for this use case. The doc says :

```
- Alias for stdin, analogous to the use of - in other command  line  utilities,  meaning
  that  the  script  will  be read from stdin, and the rest of the options are passed to
  that script.

-- Indicate the end of node options. Pass the rest of the arguments to the script.

   If no script filename or eval/print script is supplied prior to this,  then  the  next
   argument will be used as a script filename.
```

So just do the following :

```
$ cat script.js | node - args1 args2 ...
```

For example, this will returns "hello world" :

```
$ echo "console.log(process.argv[2], process.argv[3])" | node - hello world
```

Answer (score 3):

This isn't pretty, but works.

The call to `node` is going to launch the REPL, so your problem should be equivalent to setting / using `argv` manually from the terminal. Try doing something like:

```
// argv.js
process.argv[1] = 'asdf';
process.argv[2] = '1234';
```

and doing `cat argv.js dumpargs.js | node`.

Comment: AFAIK there is no way to launch the `node` REPL with a preset `argv`, like the `-s` option for `bash`.